# Remote akka actors on android?

Tags: android, scala, sbt-android-plugin

Im trying to make a simple remote connection to a actor using akka as I normally do but Im sure there something else I need to do when using akka from android can anyone help?

```
import akka.actor.Actor.remote

// Establish Connection to Remote Actor                
val server = remote.actorFor(remoteActorID, rIP, rPort)
```

I get te following stack trace:

```
04-28 09:57:13.114: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18536): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-741
        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at akka.actor.Actor$.remote(Actor.scala:115)
        at edu.spsu.rgoodwin.networking.api.RemoteConnection.<init>(RemoteConnection.scala:18)
        at edu.spsu.rgoodwin.csrAndroidApp.ClientConfigActivity.routerRegistration(ClientConfigActivity.scala:234)
        at edu.spsu.rgoodwin.csrAndroidApp.ClientConfigActivity$$anon$1.run(ClientConfigActivity.scala:71)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at akka.util.ReflectiveAccess$Remote$.<init>(ReflectiveAccess.scala:52)
        at akka.util.ReflectiveAccess$Remote$.<clinit>(ReflectiveAccess.scala)
        ... 5 more
        Caused by: akka.config.ConfigurationException: Event Handler specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.EventHandler$DefaultListener] due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.EventHandler$DefaultListener]
        [localhost_0e3e4c40-913a-11e1-b984-660379e93466]
        at akka.event.EventHandler$$anonfun$1.apply(EventHandler.scala:231)
        at akka.event.EventHandler$$anonfun$1.apply(EventHandler.scala:223)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
        at akka.event.EventHandler$.<init>(EventHandler.scala:223)
        at akka.event.EventHandler$.<clinit>(EventHandler.scala)
        ... 7 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.EventHandler$DefaultListener
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
        at akka.util.ReflectiveAccess$.getClassFor(ReflectiveAccess.scala:222)
        at akka.event.EventHandler$$anonfun$1.apply(EventHandler.scala:225)
        ... 12 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/event/EventHandler$DefaultListener
        ... 17 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.EventHandler$DefaultListener
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
```

Comment: Is the akka jar deployed on the android client?  The no class def exception seems to indicate its not.

Comment: I used my build.sbt file to include akka and the app work fine until I request an connection to the remote actor.

//Akka

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "se.scalablesolutions.akka" % "akka-actor" % "1.3"

libraryDependencies += "se.scalablesolutions.akka" % "akka-actor" % "1.3"

libraryDependencies += "se.scalablesolutions.akka" % "akka-remote" % "1.3"

libraryDependencies += "se.scalablesolutions.akka" % "akka-stm" % "1.3"

Answer (score 7):

I got it working with Akka 2.0.2 and Android 2.3.3. What you need to do is:

1. Workaround that Akka jars include multiple reference.conf at the same path which proguard does not like. Do this by removing the reference.conf from the jars but instead including a custom reference.conf which includes config from *both* files in the jars.
2. Configure Proguard to include classes from akka that are referenced by reflection and to ignore warnings about sun.misc.Unsafe. My config: https://gist.github.com/3307987
3. Upgrade Netty to 3.3.1 (fixes problems with its usage of sun.misc.Unsafe)

Answer (score 3):

Everything needs to be deployed In a single jar. See [Is using Scala on Android worth it? Is there a lot of overhead? Problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906532/is-using-scala-on-android-worth-it-is-there-a-lot-of-overhead-problems) for more details of deploying Scala to android.